# Как sys.path добавлять относительные пути для поиска модулей?

Tags: python, файловая-система

Как `sys.path` добавлять относительные пути для поиска модулей?

Answer (score 3):

Заинтересовало, спросил гугла.
http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html

Например, чтобы добавить каталог /home/me/mypy в пути, просто выполните:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")
```

Ещё есть переменная окружения PYTHONPATH, в которой можно задать список директорий, разделённыех ':' для sys.path

Был такой вопрос на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder), почитайте. Должно хватить добавления пустого `__init__.py` в директорию ./src и `import src.modulllll` в Вашу программу для модуля modulllll (текущая директория в поиске есть). Или `sys.path.append('src')` и `import modulllll`

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы узнать как работать с относительными путями. Например если написать sys.path.append("./src"), где src - директория с какими то модулями, то эти модули не импортируются. Есть ли какие нибудь другие возможности импортирования модулей не из текущей директории?

Comment: Добавлено в ответ

Answer (score 2):

В `sys.path[0]` содержится путь до директории в которой находится скрипт, поэтому относительные пути (да и абсолютные тоже) можно добавлять так:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../../modules'))
```

Comment: Не надо использовать для путей `/`, используйте `os.path.join()`.